# Change math font size only in one section

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I'm trying to modify the math environment font size but only in a defined part of my document. `\DeclareMathSizes{a}{b}{c}{d}` works fine but affects the whole document. Is there a simple way to change the math font size?

EDIT: I'm using Texlive 6.1.1 with pdfLaTex.
The document class is book with Adobe Utopia font

Comment: Please tell us which TeX distribution (MikTeX?, TeXlive?, etc), TeX format (pdfLaTeX?, XeLaTeX?, LuaLaTeX?, etc), document class, and font family (or families) you use.

Comment: Umm, TeXlive versions are typically 4-digit years, not something like "6.1.1". (I suspect "6.1.1" is the version number of the font-end program you use to invoke pdfLaTeX.)

Comment: I guess you're right, from the command "tex --version" I get the output: TeX Live 2013/Debian